# Raspberry Arduino communication via pyserial stops after a day

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I connected a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino via USB. Arduino is getting data from the world via sensors (EC and temperature sensor) and writing this data to serial. The Raspberry is writing this data into a database.

The Arduino sketch:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

int R1= 500;
int Ra=25; //Resistance of powering Pins
int ECPin= A0;
int ECGround=A1;
int ECPower =A4;

float PPMconversion=0.7; 
float TemperatureCoef = 0.019; 
float K=2.88;

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10          // Data wire For Temp Probe is plugged into pin 10 on the Arduino
const int TempProbePossitive =8;  //Temp Probe power connected to pin 9
const int TempProbeNegative=9;    //Temp Probe Negative connected to pin 8

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.


float Temperature=10;
float EC=0;
float EC25 =0;
int ppm =0;


float raw= 0;
float Vin= 5;
float Vdrop= 0;
float Rc= 0;
float buffer=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(TempProbeNegative , OUTPUT ); //seting ground pin as output for tmp probe
  digitalWrite(TempProbeNegative , LOW );//Seting it to ground so it can sink current
  pinMode(TempProbePossitive , OUTPUT );//ditto but for positive
  digitalWrite(TempProbePossitive , HIGH );
  pinMode(ECPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(ECPower,OUTPUT);//Setting pin for sourcing current
  pinMode(ECGround,OUTPUT);//setting pin for sinking current
  digitalWrite(ECGround,LOW);//We can leave the ground connected permanantly

  delay(100);// gives sensor time to settle
  sensors.begin();
  delay(100);
  R1=(R1+Ra);// Taking into acount Powering Pin Resitance

};

void loop()
{
  GetEC();
  PrintReadings();  // Cals Print routine [below main loop]
  delay(20000);
}

void GetEC(){
  sensors.requestTemperatures();// Send the command to get temperatures
  Temperature=sensors.getTempCByIndex(0); //Stores Value in Variable
  digitalWrite(ECPower,HIGH);
  raw= analogRead(ECPin);
  raw= analogRead(ECPin);// This is not a mistake, First reading will be low beause if charged a capacitor
  digitalWrite(ECPower,LOW);

  Vdrop= (Vin*raw)/1024.0;
  Rc=(Vdrop*R1)/(Vin-Vdrop);
  Rc=Rc-Ra; //acounting for Digital Pin Resitance
  EC = 1000/(Rc*K);

  EC25  =  EC/ (1+ TemperatureCoef*(Temperature-25.0));
  ppm=(EC25)*(PPMconversion*1000);


}

void PrintReadings(){
  Serial.print("Rc: ");
  Serial.print(Rc);
  Serial.print(" EC: ");
  Serial.print(EC25);
  Serial.print(" Simens  ");
  Serial.print(ppm);
  Serial.print(" ppm  ");
  Serial.print(Temperature);
  Serial.println(" *C ");
  Serial.print("Vdrop: ");
  Serial.println(Vdrop);
  Serial.print("Rc: ");
  Serial.println(Rc);
  Serial.print(EC);
  Serial.println("Siemens");
};
```

code on Raspberry Pi:

```
import serial
import time
import re
import sqlite3

for com in range(0,4):
  try:
    PORT = '/dev/ttyACM'+str(com)
    BAUD = 9600
    board = serial.Serial(PORT,BAUD)
    board.close()
    break
  except:
    pass

DEVICE = '/dev/ttyACM'+str(com)
BAUD = 9600
s = serial.Serial(DEVICE, BAUD)

conn=sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()

#s.open()
time.sleep(5) # der Arduino resettet nach einer Seriellen Verbindung, daher muss kurz gewartet werden

#s.write("test");

while True:
    response = s.readline()
    numbers = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", response)
    if len(numbers) == 4:
            temp = numbers[3]
            ec = numbers[1]
            result = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sensordata (temp, ec) VALUES ({temp}, {ec})".form$
            conn.commit()
    print response
```

Data is written for about 24 hours on Raspberry side, then I get no serial output from Arduino any more. Same problem when I restart the python script again. When I restart the python script and serial communication is started again, the Arduino resets. I did not change this default behaviour. The fact that I still do not get data via serial shows me that it is no memory problem on the Arduino side. One more hint, that it must be a problem with the Raspberry, do I get from the fact that rebooting Raspberry solves the problem and the data is logged for another 24 hours.

Is anybody curious enough to give me a hint, how to establish a solid communication?

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions. On the Raspberry add some delay to the main loop so that the CPU is no 100% used. That's probably not the problem but it may help. On the Arduino add other serial prints in the GetEC function (that you will ignore on the Raspberry), so that you see if it always stops at the same line.

Comment: Thx, ChatterOne for your comment. Did not receive any email in order to recognize your activity. Somehow python manage to add a delay anyway. According to the command line tool top there is very much idle time. Yes, I added serial printing after each command and that led me to further observations, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.

When I added massive serial printing on the Arduino side I found out that there is not really nothing received on the Raspberry side but much less, so that my python program could just not parse what the Arduino sketch was sending. Another observation was this:

When I watched the serial device with

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0
```

I got a very similar effect and could reproduce the problem. Due to the massive debug printing I added on the Arduino side I saw some characters received via pyserial that my python script was printing but the communication was seriously hurt by this screen command. And watching the serial device via screen I saw much more characters as if screen stole the show. It was a mess that I did not manage to clean up and I had to reboot the Raspberry. But told me that the problem must be on the Raspberry side.

What solved my problem was trying this communication pattern:

https://github.com/gskielian/Arduino-DataLogging/blob/master/PySerial/README.md

Don't understand completely what the author mean by 'HOWEVER, be careful that the Arduino is not constantly sending data to your program -- you will likely encounter errors from the buffer overfilling.'

The Arduino is now asked for data and responds instead of sending continuously.

This is all still mysterious to me but my question is answered and the Raspberry is now successfully receiving sensor data for 6 days.